# Endpoint for venue stats (checkins) without auth

Tags: api, authorization, foursquare, endpoint

I'm building a 'social media widget' for work's website. I'm now adding Foursquare to it and would like to use the Foursquare API to display all the checkins and tips left at our 29 locations. I don't need any user data but when I look through the Endpoint pages on the dev site and select the venue platform API, it greys out the stats endpoint. The tips endpoint is ok to use though so this isn't the issue.

Is there a way to access the number of checkins at a venue without going through authorisation? I just need the number of checkins.

Thanks,
Colin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've now successfully been able to get the data I needed. I used the `/venues/` endpoint with the id of the venues that 'we' own. I then bundled these into a `/multi/` endpoint request (I used an array of calls to get over the 5 request limit). My jQuery code is below (I'm on a classic ASP server and without loading other libraries can't use JSON).

```
var endpoint = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/multi?requests=";
var numbers = new Array();
numbers[0] ="/venues/[VENUE ID],/venues/[VENUE ID],/venues/[VENUE ID],/venues/[VENUE ID],/venues/[VENUE ID]";
numbers[1] = "/venues/[VENUE ID],/venues/[VENUE ID],/venues/[VENUE ID],/venues/[VENUE ID],/venues/[VENUE ID]";
numbers[2] = "/venues/[VENUE ID],/venues/[VENUE ID],/venues/[VENUE ID],/venues/[VENUE ID],/venues/[VENUE ID]";
numbers[3] = "/venues/[VENUE ID],/venues/[VENUE ID],/venues/[VENUE ID],/venues/[VENUE ID],/venues/[VENUE ID]";
numbers[4] = "/venues/[VENUE ID],/venues/[VENUE ID]";
var auth_string = "&client_id=[CLIENT ID]&client_secret=[CLIENT SECRET]&v=[DATE in YYYYMMDD]";
    var checkins = 0;
    var tips = 0;
    $.each(numbers,function(index,value) {
        $.getJSON(endpoint + numbers[index] + auth_string,function(json){
            $.each(json.response.responses,function(index){
                checkins = checkins + json.response.responses[index].response.venue.stats.checkinsCount;
                tips = tips + json.response.responses[index].response.venue.stats.tipCount;
            });
            $("#foursq #checkins").html("Checkins: " + checkins + "<br />");
            $("#foursq #tips").html("Tips: " + tips);
        });
    });
```

This basically just loops through every venue grabs the stats for checkinsCount and tipCount and then adds them to the total. It then prints these into wherever you want to display. I've found an issue with the count though as if you don't print the values off outside of the 'getJSON' loop it becomes 0.

Hope this helps anyone else doing something similar

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with the [Foursquare Venues Platform](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/venues)?
This relatively new part of the API supports quering the venue "database" without an "acting user". Of course you still will have to register your application with Foursquare.

But, a small tip: if you query the "here now" data from Foursquare without an "acting user", you'll only see the first letter of the first name, and the last name. (So names like "C. Wren " or "G. Horck"). If you use a "personal" account, you can see the full name of people you're friends with. Depending on the size of your organisation, it could be cool to mark all collegues as friends, so you can display more information about the people.

### Update:

Some other data, like the `/stats` endpoint, are only available to venue owners. The only way to prove that is to authenticate like an owner, so in that case you have to get an access_token for the venue owner. I'm afraid you can't bypass that.

Comment: Thanks Grad, I've been looking at it but that API documentation says that the `https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/VENUE_ID/stats` endpoint requires an acting user. I'm only really displaying the number for tips and checkins so any user data really for this project is over kill

Comment: Hmmm... you're right. The `/stats` endpoint indeed requires an acting user. I know they're in the process of converting these endpoints (at least, they were over half a year ago :s). (I was looking for the `/herenow` endpoint, and they opened up that one).

But I think you can't circumvent it. You'll just have to use your own account or create a new account just for the API calls.

Comment: I didn't know the `/stats` endpoint, but it seems like it's only for venue owners. That's why you would need to authenticate as a user. (Updated my answer as well)

Comment: Thanks for updating it. I'll have a butch at the `/herenow` endpoint and see if it will give me the info I want. Funnily enough because of the way here now works the sample they put on the dev site has no users there now :P I'll mark as answer as it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I was just about to repeat this question as the answers don't satisfy me. Indeed, answers are focused on stats, which would be very useful but are manager-centric.

The number of check-in is easy to access, but is part of the venue object. So you just have to look for a venue detail with its ID (https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/venues) to get the number of check-ins.

Quite logical, but if this can help a lost developer passing by :)